# passing a class as a parameter c++

Tags: c++

Instead of doing this and keep on making redundant code for everything:

```
Molecule::Molecule(Hydrogenyx& h){
    //some code
}

Molecule::Molecule(Carbonyx& c){
    //same code as hydro
}

Molecule::Molecule(Sulphuryx& s){
    //same code
}
```

is there a way I can just make it so it can look like this?:

```
Molecule::Molecule(x){
    //code that can apply to all
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a separate class for every atom? Seems very cluttered to me.

Comment: Since you are working with chemical elements, you should take advantage of inheritance and polymorphism in C++. Create a class, say Element, and have the chemical elements inherite attributes and properties as needed. Then you could do something like this **Molecule::Molecule(Element * element) { // code that can apply to all }**.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way I can just make it so it can look like this?:

Sure. You can use a member function template.

Declaration:

```
template <typename T> Molecule(T& t);
```

Implementation:

```
template <typename T>
Molecule::Molecule(T& t){
   // The common code.
}
```